# Showing that $\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{23}{1-x^{23}}-\frac{11}{1-x^{11}} \right)=6$

Tags: limits

How does one evaluate the following limit?
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{23}{1-x^{23}}-\frac{11}{1-x^{11}} \right)$$
The answer is $6$.

How does one justify this answer?

Edit: So it really was just combine the fraction and use L'hopital's rule twice (because function and its first derivative are of indeterminate form at $x=1$). This problem is more straightforward than it seems at first.

Comment: Put the fractions over a common denominator.  You get $\frac {P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P,Q$ are some polynomials.  If the limit exists $(x-1)$ will divide both $P$ and $Q.$   Do the division.  Evaluate at $1.$  if you still get an indeterminate, then do the division by $(x-1)$ as many times as necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both fractions are unbounded as $x\rightarrow 1$. But if we rewrite
$$\frac{23}{1-x^{23}}-\frac{11}{1-x^{11}}=\dfrac{23(1-x^{11})-11(1-x^{23})}{(1-x^{23})(1-x^{11})}=\dfrac{11x^{23}-23x^{11}+12}{1-x^{23}-x^{11}+x^{34}}$$
we can use L'Hopital since both sides tend to 0 as $x$ tends to 1. Differentiating both sides give
$$\dfrac{253x^{22}-253x^{10}}{-23x^{22}-11x^{10}+34x^{33}}=253\dfrac{x^{12}-1}{-23x^{12}-11+34x^{23}}$$
Both sides still tend to 0, so we differentiate again and get
$$253\dfrac{12x^{11}}{-276x^{11}+782x^{22}}$$
which tends to
$$253\dfrac{12}{-276+782}=6$$

Comment: I didn't expect this many responses to my question, but your approach is the clearest and most standard of all of the other approaches. Also, I didn't think combining the fraction was necessary but it is. Because I see that it is much better to deal with indeterminate forms of $\frac 00$ instead of $\infty - \infty$, because $\frac 00$ prompts us to use immediately l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @user373314 This is a very interesting comment. In France, at least what I have seen, L'Hopital's rule is hardly ever used, if even taught at all. The standard way to compute limits is by *[développements limités](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9veloppement_limit%C3%A9)* (that is, Taylor series with $O$ or $o$ notation). However, by reading american calculus books, I have discovered L'Hopital's rule is much more used there. They are mostly equivalent anyway, but this difference in teaching is reflected in questions and answers on MSE.

Comment: See also [this question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814734/the-case-for-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule) about L'Hopital (which, coming from France, is something I may have used maybe 5 times in my life).

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I have seen this. Good question. L'Hopital's rule seems to have a bad reputation, however, it's interesting to see in Franklin's *Advanced calculus*, that even Taylor series may be derived from L'Hopital's rule. It's not bad at all, but it must be used carefully.

Answer (score 4):

As $t\to0$, we have

$$\frac{23}{1-(1+t)^{23}}=-\frac{23}{23t+253t^2+O(t^3)}=-\frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{1}{1+11t+O(t^2)}=-\frac{1}{t}\left(1-11t+O(t^2)\right)$$

Likewise

$$\frac{11}{1-(1+t)^{11}}=-\frac{11}{11t+55t^2+O(t^3)}=-\frac{1}{t}\cdot\frac{1}{1+5t+O(t^2)}=-\frac{1}{t}\left(1-5t+O(t^2)\right)$$

So the difference is

$$-\frac{1}{t}\left(1-11t-1+5t+O(t^2)\right)=6+O(t)$$

And your limit is $6$.

Answer (score 4):

*This answer does not use L'Hopital ([personal taste](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814734/the-case-for-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule)), only a standard identity restated below, the binomial theorem, and a straightforward Taylor expansion to first order at $0$.*

Using the identity $1-x^{2n+1} = (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{2n} x^k$, we can rewrite
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{23}{1-x^{23}} -  \frac{11}{1-x^{11}} 
&= \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{23}{\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k} -  \frac{11}{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k} \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{23\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k} -  \frac{11\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k} \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}\left(23\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k - 11\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k \right)\\
\end{align*}$$
Let us focus on the parenthesis (the first factor converges to $\frac{1}{11\cdot 23}$ by continuity, the second is the problematic one that will be "offset" by the parenthesis).

Writing $x=1+h)$ (where we will have $h\to 0$), we get, for any fixed integer $n$,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(1+h)^k
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{\ell=0}^k \binom{k}{\ell} h^\ell \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}(1+kh +o(h)) \\
&= (n+1)+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}h +o(h)
\end{align*}$$
when $h\to 0$, as $n$ is a constant. In particular, this implies
$$\begin{align*}
23\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k - 11\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k
&= 23\cdot 11+23\cdot \frac{11\cdot10}{2}h - 11\cdot 23-11\cdot \frac{22\cdot 23}{2}h + o(h)\\
&= 23\cdot 11\cdot (-6h) + o(h)\\
&= 23\cdot 11\cdot 6(1-x) + o(1-x)
\end{align*}$$
Overall, we thus have
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{23}{1-x^{23}} -  \frac{11}{1-x^{11}} 
&= \frac{23\cdot 11}{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k}\cdot\frac{6(1-x)+o(1-x)}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{23\cdot 11}{\sum_{k=0}^{10}x^k\sum_{k=0}^{22}x^k}\cdot (6+o(1)) \xrightarrow[x\to1]{} \frac{23\cdot 11}{23\cdot 11} \cdot 6 = 6
\end{align*}$$
as claimed.

Comment: Darn, took much longer to type than expected. Oh, well.

Comment: I tried an approach like yours originally but I got stuck at dealing with that $\frac 1{1-x}$. Your solution to this dilemma was simply to write $x=1+h$ (for $h > 0$)? I guess since we're taking the limit to $1$ from both sides, that must be why.

Comment: @user373314 Yes, basically. The rationale is that while it does not change anything mathematically,  I am **much** more comfortable with standard machinery (Taylor expansions, limits, asymptotics) at $0$ that at a finite non-zero point.

Comment: Well done.  +1 .

Comment: Always easier to have something go to zero.

Answer (score 2):

That is the same as

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{23}{1-(1-x)^{23}}-\frac{11}{1-(1-x)^{11}}\right]=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{23}{23x-253x^2}-\frac{11}{11-55x^2}\right]$$
(we exploited the binomial theorem and neglected terms with high order, since *we can*, see the comments below) or as
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{1}{1-11x}-\frac{1}{1-5x}\right]=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{-5+11}{(1-11x)(1-5x)}\right]=11-5=\color{red}{6}.$$
With the same approach, for any $n,m\in\mathbb{N}^+$,
$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{m}{1-x^m}-\frac{n}{1-x^n}\right]= \color{red}{\frac{m-n}{2}}.$$
In other terms, the function $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{1-x^n}$ has a simple pole at $x=1$. If we remove the contribute given by such simple pole, we are left with a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $x=1$. In particular, $$\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{n}{1-x^n}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right]=\frac{n-1}{2}.$$

Comment: I don't like very much to "neglect terms". There is the notation $O(x^3)$ for this purpose (or $o(x^2)$ if you prefer). More correct, and less dangerous: what happens when all previous terms cancel, you are left with $0$ while there is indeed some nonzero function of $x$? For instance, how do you know in advance that you can neglect terms of degree $>2$, but not those of degree $2$? Of course, I don't know either with the $O$ notation, but at least if I fail I will know.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: $$\frac{23}{23x-253x^2+o(x^2)}=\frac{23}{23x-253x^2}+o(1)$$ hence we are allowed to do that.

Comment: Yes, but we would also be allowed to do that at order $2$. But it would fail, and you would not know, unless you have mentally used the correct notation, but then why not write it? Bad habit, IMO

Comment: Otherwise, you may simply keep the terms with high order, then check in the last steps that they do not matter.

Comment: I know it works here, because even if there are terms left, they tend to $0$ and only contribute by addition, so no risk. But if you have to justify this, it will take at least as much work as if you had done things cleanly to begin with. Not worth it. And I have seen limits for which you need to keep track of terms of degree, say, $6$, so it's not a good advice, to neglect terms, when you get the same result by using a more correct notation, that does not need extra justification.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: do not get me wrong, some justification in my answer *was* actually lacking, so I modified it according to your suggestion. And thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{x \to 1}\pars{{23 \over 1 - x^{23}} - {11 \over 1 - x^{11}}}} =
\lim_{x \to 1}\bracks{{1 \over 1-x}
\pars{{23 \over \sum_{k = 0}^{22}x^{k}} - {11 \over \sum_{k = 0}^{10}x^{k}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{x \to 1}
\bracks{23\,{\sum_{k = 1}^{22}k\,x^{k - 1} \over
\pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{22}x^{k}}^{2}} -
11\,{\sum_{k = 1}^{10}k\,x^{k - 1} \over \pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{10}x^{k}}^{2}}}
\qquad\pars{~By\ L'H\hat{o}pital\ Rule}
\\[5mm] = &\
23\,{\sum_{k = 1}^{22}k \over \pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{22}1}^{2}} -
11\,{\sum_{k = 1}^{10}k \over \pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{10}1}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\cancel{23}\,{22\cancel{\pars{22 + 1}}/2 \over \cancel{23^{2}}}}_{\ds{=\ 11}}\ -\
\underbrace{\cancel{11}\,{10\cancel{\pars{10 + 1}}/2 \over \cancel{11^{2}}}}_{\ds{=\ 5}}\ = \ 11 - 5 = \color{#f00}{6}
\end{align}

Comment: How did you justify your second equality? Because $\frac 1{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$, an *infinite* series. How did you get finite series in the numerator? By squaring the denominator?

Comment: @user373314 Note that $1 - x^{n} = \left(1 - x\right)\left(1 + x + x^{2} + \cdots + x^{n - 1}\right) = \left(1 - x\right)\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}x^{k}$ for $n = 1, 2,3,\ldots$. They are $\color{#f00}{finite\ sums}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely the best method to solve this question:
$$Let\space L = \lim_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{p}{1-x^{p}}-\frac{q}{1-x^{q}} \right)$$$\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$ $\space$       $\space$              **Replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$**


$$\space L = \lim_{{x} \to 1} \left(\frac{p}{1-{\frac{1}{x}}^{p}}-\frac{q}{1-{\frac{1}{x}}^{q}} \right)$$
$$\space L = \lim_{{x} \to 1} \left(\frac{-px^p}{1-{{x}}^{p}}-\frac{-qx^q}{1-{{x}}^{q}} \right)$$
**Adding both the equations we get $2L={p-q}$**
And we are done

Answer (score 1):

$$ =\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{23 - 23x^{11} -11 + 11x^{23}}{1 - x^{11} - x^{23} + x^{34}} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{-23\cdot 11 x^{10} + 11\cdot 23 x^{22}}{-11x^{10} - 23x^{22} + 34x^{33}} =$$$$= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{-23\cdot 11 \cdot 10 x^9 + 11\cdot 23 \cdot 22x^{21}}{-11\cdot 10 \cdot x^9 - 23\cdot 22x^{21} + 34\cdot 33 x^{32}} = \frac {3036}{506} = 6 $$
where we used Hopital twice

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_\limits{x\to1}\frac {23(1-x^{11})-11(1-x^{23})}{(1-x^{11})(1-x^{23})}$

$\lim_\limits{x\to1}\frac {12-23x^{11}+ 11x^{23}}{(1-x^{11})(1-x^{23})}$

Now we could apply L'Hopitals at this point, or we can use algebra.

Using algebra, numerator and denominator both divide by $(x-1)^2$

$1-x^{11} = (1-x)\sum_\limits{i=0}^{10} x^i\\ 
1-x^{23} = (1-x)\sum_\limits{i=0}^{22} x^i$

$11x^{23} -23x^{11}+ 12 = (x-1)(11 x^{22}\cdots 11x^{11} - 12x^{10}\cdots +12)\\ =(x-1)^2 (11x^{21} + 2\cdot11 x^{20} + 3\cdot11 x^{19}\cdots +12\cdot 11 x^{10} + 12\cdot 10 x^9\cdots +12\cdot 2x + 12 $

Evaluated at 1.

The denominator:

$\sum_\limits{i=0}^{10} x^i = 11, \sum_\limits{i=0}^{22} x^i = 23$

the numerator:

$11 \sum_\limits{i=1}^{11} i + 12 \sum_\limits{i=1}^{11} i = (23)(11)(12)/2$

and the ratio  $= 6$

Answer (score 1):

The following standard formula is well known $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{n} - 1}{x - 1} = n = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(1 + t)^{n} - 1}{t}\tag{1}$$ and it appears that we can go very easily to the next step if $n$ is a positive integer and derive the formula $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{n} - 1 - n(x - 1)}{(x - 1)^{2}} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(1 + t)^{n} - 1 - nt}{t^{2}} = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}\tag{2}$$ The simplest approach to prove $(2)$ is to use Binomial theorem. Hence we have $$x^{n} - 1 = n(x - 1) + \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}(x - 1)^{2} + o((x - 1)^{2})$$ and therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{n}{1 - x^{n}} &= \dfrac{n}{n(1 - x) - \dfrac{n(n - 1)}{2}(x - 1)^{2} + o((x - 1)^{2})}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{1 - x}\left(1 - \frac{n - 1}{2}(1 - x) + o((1 - x))\right)^{-1}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{1 - x}\left(1 + \frac{n - 1}{2}(1 - x) + o(1 - x)\right)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{1 - x} + \frac{n - 1}{2} + o(1)\tag{3}
\end{align}
It follows that $$\frac{n}{1 - x^{n}} - \frac{m}{1 - x^{m}} = \frac{n - m}{2} + o(1)$$ and hence $$\lim_{x \to 1}\left(\frac{n}{1 - x^{n}} - \frac{m}{1 - x^{m}}\right) = \frac{n - m}{2}$$ and putting $n = 23, m = 11$ we get the desired limit as $6$.

---

The gymnastics of series division to reach $(3)$ can be avoided in another manner by using $(2)$ directly. We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{n}{1 - x^{n}} - \frac{m}{1 - x^{m}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{n(1 - x^{m}) - m(1 - x^{n})}{(1 - x^{n})(1 - x^{m})}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{n(1 - x^{m}) - mn(1 - x) + mn(1 - x) - m(1 - x^{n})}{(1 - x^{n})(1 - x^{m})}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{n(1 - x^{m}) - mn(1 - x) + mn(1 - x) - m(1 - x^{n})}{\dfrac{(1 - x^{n})(1 - x^{m})}{(1 - x)^{2}}\cdot(1 - x)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{mn}\lim_{x \to 1}n\frac{1 - x^{m} - m(1 - x)}{(1 - x)^{2}} - m\frac{1 - x^{n} - n(1 - x)}{(1 - x)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{mn}\left(\frac{nm(1 - m)}{2} - \frac{mn(1 - n)}{2}\right)\text{ (using (2))}\notag\\
&= \frac{n - m}{2}\notag
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Write $P_n(x)=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n$; then our function is
$$
\frac{23P_{10}(x)-11P_{22}(x)}{(1-x)P_{22}(x)P_{10}(x)}
$$
We can notice that
$$
\lim_{x\to1}P_{22}(x)P_{10}(x)=23\cdot11
$$
so we just need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{11P_{22}(x)-23P_{10}(x)}{x-1}=
11P_{22}'(1)-23P_{10}'(1)
$$
by definition of derivative. Since
$$
P_n'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\dots+nx^{n-1}
$$
we have
$$
P_n'(1)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
Thus, reinserting $23\cdot11$ at the denominator, our limit is
$$
\frac{11\cdot22\cdot23-23\cdot10\cdot11}{2\cdot23\cdot11}=
\frac{22-10}{2}=6
$$

More generally,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{m}{1-x^m}-\frac{n}{1-x^n}\right)
&=
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{mP_{n-1}(x)-nP_{m-1}(x)}{(1-x)P_{m-1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)}
\\[6px]
&=
\frac{nP_{m-1}'(1)-mP_{n-1}'(1)}{mn}
\\[6px]
&=
\frac{n(m-1)m-m(n-1)n}{2mn}
\\[6px]
&=
\frac{m-n}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Dumping my answer here to a different but similar question which was labeled as a duplicate and would no longer accept the answer that I had already typed.

$\lim\limits_{t\to1}\frac{5}{1-t^5}-\frac{2}{1-t^2}=$
$\lim\limits_{t\to1}\frac{5}{(1-t)(1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4)}-\frac{2}{(1-t)(1+t)}=$
$\lim\limits_{t\to1}\frac{5+5t-2-2t-2t^2-2t^3-2t^4}{(1-t)(1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4)(1+t)}$

Clearly the numerator evaluates to $0$ when $t=1$ so $t-1$ must be a factor.

$\lim\limits_{t\to1}\frac{5+5t-2-2t-2t^2-2t^3-2t^4}{(1-t)(1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4)(1+t)}=$
$\lim\limits_{t\to1}\frac{2t^4+2t^3+2t^2-3t-3}{(t-1)(1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4)(1+t)}=$
$\lim\limits_{t\to1}\frac{2t^3+4t^2+6t+3}{(1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4)(1+t)}=$
$\frac{2+4+6+3}{(1+1+1+1+1)(1+1)}=\frac{15}{(5)(2)}=\frac32$

(Long division was used to obtain $\frac{2t^4+2t^3+2t^2-3t-3}{t-1}=2t^3+4t^2+6t+3$ )